# How to sum NaN in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have to sum two values obtained by `np.average` as

```
for i in x :
    a1 = np.average(function1(i))
    a2 = np.average(function2(i))
    plt.plot(i, a1+a2, 'o')
```

But the `np.average` may return `NaN`. Then, only points for which both `a1` and `a2` are available will be calculated.

How can I use zero instead of `NaN` to make the sum for all points?

I tried to find a function in numpy to do so, but `numpy.nan_to_num` is for arrays.

Comment: Have you tried using `np.nanmean` instead of `np.average`?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser excellent solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use :

```
clean_x = x[~np.isnan(x)]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use numpy like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = [1, 2, np.nan]
a_sum = np.nansum(a)
a_mean = np.nanmean(a)

print('a = ', a) # [1, 2, nan]
print("a_sum = {}".format(a_sum)) # 3.0
print("a_mean = {}".format(a_mean)) # 1.5
```